# PHP is not able to call one object in a json file

Tags: php, json, api

I want to have my output not like this I want to have for example only the Phone print out like this "45656731". if I try this > `echo $result->queryResult->EntityResults->Entity->Phone;` It does not work.

**Script**

```
<?php 
require_once 'autoload.php';

$username = '*********************';
$password = '***************';
$authWsdl = 'https://webservices.autotask.net/atservices/1.5/atws.wsdl';
$opts = array('trace' => 1);
$client = new ATWS\Client($authWsdl, $opts);
$zoneInfo = $client->getZoneInfo($username);

$authOpts = array(
    'login' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'trace' => 1,   // Allows us to debug by getting the XML requests sent
);
$wsdl = str_replace('.asmx', '.wsdl', $zoneInfo->getZoneInfoResult->URL);
$client = new ATWS\Client($wsdl, $authOpts);

// Instantiate a Query object, designed to make complex
// queries simple.
$query = new ATWS\AutotaskObjects\Query('Contact');

$firstnameField = new ATWS\AutotaskObjects\QueryField('firstname');
$firstnameField->addExpression('Equals', 'Jeroen');

$query->addField($firstnameField);

// If you want to debug the XML produced by the Query object
// print($query->asXml());

// Print the results of the query
$json = ($client->query($query));
$result = json_encode($json);
echo $result;
?>
```

**Output**

```
{"queryResult":{"EntityResults":{"Entity":{"AccountID":193,"Active":1,"AdditionalAddressInformation":"","AddressLine":"Bernhardweg 30","AddressLine1":"","AlternatePhone":"","City":"***","Country":"Netherlands","CountryID":158,"CreateDate":"2016-10-22T09:52:03.807","EMailAddress":"****************","Extension":"","ExternalID":"","FaxNumber":"","FirstName":"Jeroen","LastActivityDate":"2016-10-22T09:52:03.807","LastModifiedDate":"2016-10-22T09:52:03.937","LastName":"Jansen","MiddleInitial":null,"MobilePhone":"*******","Note":"","Notification":true,"Phone":"45656731","RoomNumber":"","State":"","Title":"","ZipCode":"******","Fields":null,"UserDefinedFields":{"UserDefinedField":null},"id":30682895,"BulkEmailOptOut":false,"SurveyOptOut":false,"FacebookUrl":"","TwitterUrl":"","LinkedInUrl":"","PrimaryContact":false}},"EntityResultType":"contact","EntityReturnInfoResults":{"EntityReturnInfo":{"DatabaseAction":"None","DuplicateStatus":{"Found":false,"Ignored":false,"MatchInfo":null,"Fields":null,"UserDefinedFields":null},"EntityId":30682895,"Message":null,"Fields":null,"UserDefinedFields":null},"Fields":null,"UserDefinedFields":null},"Errors":{"ATWSError":null,"Fields":null,"UserDefinedFields":null},"ReturnCode":1}}
```

Comment: `json_encode($json);` returns a **string**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before encoding your result in a json string, use that to retrive the phone number:

```
$json = ($client->query($query));
$phone = $json->queryResult->EntityResults->Entity->Phone;
echo $phone;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reaction! When i run the code i get an fatal error.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type ATWS\AutotaskObjects\QueryResponse as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\Api\Autotask\vendor\test.php:33 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Api\Autotask\vendor\test.php on line 33`

Comment: That's probably a wrong access to the `$json` variable, I need you to test the actual value of it... Try with a `var_dump`

Comment: OK, it means `$json` is not an array, but a query result... you must fetch it first

Answer (score 0):

It is not as hard as it looks at the first time just run this script and replace the #cats in the code with what you want to find.
Hope you get it to work!

```
function getTweets($hash_tag) {

$url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q='.urlencode($hash_tag) ;
echo "<p>Connecting to <strong>$url</strong> ...</p>";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$xml = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

//If you want to see the response from Autotask, uncomment this next part out:
//echo "<p>Response:</p>";
//echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($xml)."</pre>";

$affected = 0;
$twelement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($twelement->entry as $entry) {
    $text = trim($entry->title);
    $author = trim($entry->author->name);
    $time = strtotime($entry->published);
    $id = $entry->id;
    echo "<p>Tweet from ".$author.": <strong>".$text."</strong>  <em>Posted ".date('n/j/y g:i a',$time)."</em></p>";
}

return true ;
}

getTweets('#cats');
```

Good luck!